# Can I define an exixting css class with different attribute in a different css class?

Tags: css, class

I have a CSS class to show the portlet title :

```
.portlet-title {
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

In another css file I've a class :

```
.lfr-grid.dragging {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

now I want to call the class .portlet-title in .lfr-grid.dragging with changing the color attribute as color: #000000

Answer (score 3):

CSS is not about *calling classes*, it's about applying more or less specific styles.

*Assuming* a structure like this:

```
<div class="portlet-title">...</div>
```

which sometimes changes to this:

```
<div class="portlet-title lft-grid dragging">...</div>
```

you can simply apply a more specific style:

```
.portlet-title.lfr-grid.dragging {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the following:

```
.lfr-grid.dragging .portlet-title {
color: #000;
}
```

Note that .lfr-grid.dragging will not work in IE6 as it does not support chaining of classes.